# Using Kawa in Emacs

Tags: emacs, kawa

Are there any modes or resources for Kawa in Emacs? I've checked, but am not able to find any. Mostly, I'd like to be able to run a Kawa REPL inside of Emacs, but some kind of completion/syntax checking would be great too.

Comment: Looks like it's a Scheme implementation, so maybe look at existing Scheme or Guile support?

Comment: One of the first hits in google for "emacs kawa" is http://rdsathene.org/scheme/kawa-emacs.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have any prior experience with Kawa, but I have a "universal" way to deal with REPLs: plugin **isend** + some hacks

1. Follow the instructions in section 2 and section 3 of this article http://wenshanren.org/?p=351#sec-2 to setup isend (it's a bit tedious, please let me know if you have any problems)
2. Open a shell in Emacs, assume the buffer name is `*shell*`

   > M-x shell
3. Open Kawa REPl in `*shell*`

   > CLASSPATH=/usr/local/lib/kawa.jar && export CLASSPATH && java kawa.repl
4. Create a new buffer *test.kawa* and turn on lisp-mode `M-x lisp-mode` (you can use any mode you want)
5. Associate `*shell*` with *test.kawa* `M-x isend-associate *shell*`
6. Now type some sexps in *test.kawa*, select them and press `C-Enter` to send them `*shell*` for execution (the cursor won't move)

[image]